# i want to get a functionality like wetransfer dot com where the url change but page not refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I want to get the same functionality of sliding a div with different page content and different url but not refreshing the page and load the slider div with the content of the another page whose link is clicked without refreshing the page like in wetransfer dot com. I've tried so many things with jQuery and Ajax but didn't achieve my goal yet. Is any one help me out i'm working on it from 5 days but didn't find any solution yet. I am working on asp.net mvc platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.history.replaceState and window.history.pushState to manipulate the history of the browser without refreshing the page.

[Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method)